# WPF view not updating although INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented (.NET 5.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

In my view I have a ProgressBar which binds to a "Progress" property in my viewmodel. The viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and when the property is changed, OnPropertyChanged() is called.

The binding works however the view rarely updates the progress of the ProgressBar control. It only regularly updates when I am draging the window around with the mouse.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="500"
    Height="500"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Timer updateProgressBarTimer;
    private int progress;

    public int Progress
    {
        get => progress;
        set
        {
            this.progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        updateProgressBarTimer = new Timer(OnUpdateProgressBarTimerTick, null, 0, 50);
    }

    private void OnUpdateProgressBarTimerTick(object state)
    {
        this.Progress += 2;
        if (this.Progress > 100)
            this.Progress -= 100;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I have used INotifyPropertyChanged a lot and usually never have issues with it but I can't see the problem here.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

Comment: Beware that you're raising the event on a non-UI thread. WPF *should* marshal that back to the UI thread, but there's potentially some weirdness there

Comment: Better use a DispatcherTimer. Its Tick handler is called in the thread in which the timer was created, i.e. the UI thread. Also, if you really need to run a Task, make sure to await it *before* updating the Process property, e.g. like `Process = await Task.Run(() => { ... return p; });`

Comment: @canton7 excuse me, I forgot to remove the async and Task thing in this code example. It was just a thing I've tried out and has nothing to do with the issue. -> removed it

Comment: Be aware that `Timer` still invokes its callback in a background thread.

Comment: Exactly, `OnUpdateProgressBarTimerTick` is still called on a background thread. Use a `DispatcherTimer`, as Clemens mentioned

Comment: Since you are using a System.Timers.Timer, instead of a DispatcherTimer as Clemens suggested, your code is updating the value of the ProgressBar on the wrong thread.  I'm surprised it isn't throwing an exception.  I'm not sure that this is your problem, but I don't see anything else wrong, so I suspect that this is the case.  Use a DispatcherTimer so that the update correctly occurs on the UI thread.

Comment: @Russ It's actually System.Threading.Timer, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! DispatcherTimer solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the `System.Threading.Timer` with a `DispatcherTimer` (with **`DispatcherPriority.Normal`**) solved the problem.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: **`DispatcherPriority.Normal`** is the key word! Without **`DispatcherPriority.Normal`** `DispatcherTimer` acts like a `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: @Rekshino Where did you get that from? I'm pretty sure that's wrong

Comment: @canton7 Do you mean the "key word"?

Comment: @Rekshino You said "Without DispatcherPriority.Normal DispatcherTimer acts like a System.Threading.Timer". I'm asking for your source, as I'm pretty sure that's wrong

Comment: I meant "acts like" as how it looks at the GUI. The source is my tests. Have you tested both?

Comment: I interpret "acts like" as meaning it dispatches on a background thread, which is false